# "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" when calling subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, ioerror

I am just trying to call `tracert` and get the result as a string. It seems the `tracert` call is working correctly, because the result is displayed on the console before the error occurs.

```
    import subprocess
    import sys
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["tracert", "localhost"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    print proc.communicate()[0]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-", line 207, in <module>
    main()
  File "-", line 203, in main
    tracert("localhost")
  File "-", line 188, in tracert
    print proc.communicate()[1]
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

**UPDATE:**
I tried `logging` instead of `print`, because it is unbuffered.

```
2017-09-07 09:11:57,165 - [test] - INFO - 

Routenverfolgung zu localhost [::1]

�ber maximal 30 Hops:



  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  localhost [::1] 



Ablaufverfolgung beendet.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 885, in emit
    self.flush()
  File "-\logging\__init__.py", line 845, in flush
    self.stream.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say it's because `tracert` closes its `stdin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the `stdout` was closed and I could not write to the stream.
So the problem had nothing to do with `subprocess` at all.